# Azure says "Unsupported Token"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Azure has started giving me the following error:

> Unsupported token. Unable to initialize the authorization context.

I get this from the UI when ever I try to make a change to my application. For example, if I try to add a new client secret, or add an API Permission.  (Note that I have been able to do these things in the past.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Unsupported Token]

Because it says it is a "temporary problem" I have waited a few days in hopes that it would self correct (thinking that maybe Azure was having an issue).  But it has not changed.

When I google this error, all I can find are scripts that failed to login first.

Any ideas on what would cause this?  Or how I can go about getting more information?

Comment: Not really a solution, but I had a new Azure Active Directory Application made, and it did not have this issue with it.  I just moved my work to the new application.  (Not a great option for an established application.)

Answer (score 5):

I am also getting this issue when trying to create a client secret.
I have created a support case with Microsoft and will update here when I get more information.

Edit:
Eventually got a reply from a higher tier support engineer, they tell me this is a known issue and a fix is expected to be implemented today (9th August Australian time).

They also pointed me to here to manually create a secret via Microsoft Graph Powershell as a workaround:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/add-mgapplicationpassword?view=graph-powershell-1.0#description

Comment: Another update: Issue is still occurring for me which I advised MS support, their response:
"Already reported to Production Team, and confirmed the full roll-out and deployment will take some time to complete. Once got the ETA, will reply to you as soon as possible. "

Comment: Confirmed the UI is now allowing me to create secrets successfully again. Their fix seems to be implemented.

Answer (score 5):

I am facing same issue for a non-Microsoft AAD tenant.

When the application url with /isMSAApp is not appended with "~/false" getting this error. I have added this and able to add the client secret now. [https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/~/Overview/appId/APPLICATION_ID/isMSAApp~/false](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/%7E/Overview/appId/APPLICATION_ID/isMSAApp%7E/false).

Also as per below, if the app is owned by org below url is working too, so isMSAApp~/false could be app owned by org not personal Microsoft(MSA) account. [https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/~/Overview/appId/APPLICATION_ID](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/%7E/Overview/appId/APPLICATION_ID)

[image]

This url is giving error:
[https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/~/Overview/appId/APPLICATION_ID/isMSAApp/](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/%7E/Overview/appId/APPLICATION_ID/isMSAApp/)
[image]

Comment: Do you know/could document what the `~/false` does? This would make this (working) workaround less creepy ;)

Comment: agreed, i'd like to know what the `false` piece does...

Answer (score 2):

I'm also getting this but have managed to work around it by using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to make the request directly to the Graph API:

[image]

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/YOUR_APPLICATION_ID_HERE/addPassword

{
    "passwordCredential": {
        "displayName": "Put your description here"
    },
    "endDate": "2024-08-01T13:14:30.664Z",
    "startDate": "2023-08-02T13:14:30.664Z"
}
```

You'll need to grant consent for the `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission:

[image]

See the [Microsoft Graph Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more details.

Comment: [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) give two HTTP methods: 
`POST /applications/{id}/addPassword`
`POST /applications(appId='{appId}')/addPassword` and say that "id and appId are referred to as the Object ID and Application (Client) ID, respectively, in the Azure portal." If you get an error _"YOUR_APPLICATION_ID" does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present_, make sure that you are using the correct id. In my case I needed `Object ID` and not `Application (client) ID`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad I'm not the only one getting this error. I've never had a problem before and finding information online is next to impossible. This is the only post I've seen mentioning this issue. I'll be following along. Hopefully we get some sort of answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue trying to create a new secret. My solution:

I had the URL saved in my reminder, which I used to open my Azure App directly. After connecting manually via Azure search bar, I was able to create a secret again.

I have not investigated this further.